# Apply ANOVA tests in MATLAB neural networks.toolbox

Tags: statistics, neural-network, matlab, anova

Matlab has NN toolbox as well as ANOVA tests. I want to apply ANOVA tests for the NN model after training. How to do it? Any references or examples are welcome.

Comment: Can you specify on which dependent and independent variables you want to use the ANOVA?

Comment: I want to apply it to output of the NN. e.g. to get the p-value and check the meaning fullness of the model.

Comment: Please pardon me, but your answer sounds like you do not know at all what you want to do. Maybe you can explain in more detail what your research design / experimental design is.

Comment: In simple terms NN gives only the RMS (or alternative) error insted I want to calculate ANOVA table.

Comment: That's still not the study design. In order to to an ANOVA, you'll need multiple measurements of your dependent variable which are divided into groups by means of an independent variable. For instance, you can define the groups by the type of algorithm (e.g., SOM, RBF, or K-Means) and have, say, 10 NN trained for each group and extract 1 measure for each of these trained NNs (for instance, RMS). Then you can subject those 3 by 10 RMS values to an ANOVA and test whether RMS in those three groups are significantly different.

Comment: just as an example please check [link] (http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S1678-58782010000500010&script=sci_arttext) **table 3** I want to produce simmilar table ....

Comment: Yes, I know how an ANOVA table looks like. See their table for the definition of their independent variables (called factors there). You'll need such a study design in order to calculate an ANOVA

Comment: In the NN case factors are input variables (independent variables) of the data. So, I need a generic solution or to map ANOVA to NN in a generic way..

Comment: There is no way to answer your question if you are this vague about your design. Specify in detail which levels your input variables can take and what your dependent measure is. Or, seriously, take a textbook and find out what ANOVA is about.

Comment: I thought there is an easy way to do it in matlab. I'll http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ANOVA.html implement it soon. Not that hard at all. I start to wonder why it sounds so difficult.

Comment: It _is_ really easy to do an anova in matlab. Group your data in colums according to your independent variable and pass it as the first argument into the function `anova1`. The second argument of the function is a cell array of strings with the group names (one per column). That's it; not even worth a question on SE since it is pretty well explained in the matlab help. Your problem seems to be that you do not know what your data are and how to group them.

Comment: well in that case it's anova test for the data not for the NN ;) May be I should use the response of NN and actual output values...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your starting data looks like but here is a [reference to the ANOVA function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/bqttcvf.html) within Matlab.  I believe it's in the stats package but if you're using the NN toolbox I think you probably will have access to the stats toolbox too.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of these two toolboxes. I want to train with NN toolbox e.g. with SOM, RBF, or K-Means and than apply the anova tests. The question is how to do it?